# REST API URL design for only single property from performance viewpoint

Tags: rest, api, server-side

I am developing REST API and Frontend as a microservice. I know some basic principles of URL design, but there is a performance issue and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

For the convenience of displaying the webpage, I'd like to get certain information about more than 100 resources per page. (Actually, BFF exists as an orchestration layer)

Since the target resource includes the aggregation result from a large amount of database record, it takes about 3 seconds per request. However, the information I want on the webpage is only a part of it, and it doesn't require complex aggregation to get it, and that makes the response time much shorter.

Take a case as an example.

There is a resource of `article`, and return the resource data in `articles/:id` containing a complex aggregation. But in this case, all I need is a count of comments, which can be quickly obtained by issuing a SQL `count` statement without a counter cache.

However, when examining REST API design, I've never seen a case where a GET request that returns only a specific field.

And in microservices, API should only return resource state in loosely coupled situation, so I think it shouldn't be focused on specific fields.

What kind of URL design or performance optimization can be considered in the face of performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

REST is the architectural style of the world wide web; the style and the web were developed in parallel in the 1990s.  Given the usage patterns and technical constraints of the time, the attention of the style is focused more on the caching of large grained documents, rather than trying to reduce the latency of transport.

So you would be more likely to design your representation so that count is present somewhere in the representation, and addressable to that you can call attention to it.  Thus: [fragments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5).

So if you already had a resource with the identifier `/articles`, and having the comment count was important enough, then you might treat the representation like a DTO ([Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)), and simply include the comment count in the representation, accessible via some identifier like `/articles#comment-count`.

That's not necessarily a great fit for your use case.

An alternative is to just introduce a stand-alone comment count resource.

> Any information that can be named can be a resource -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

If you are actually doing REST, then the spelling of the URI don't matter (consider - when is the last time you cared where the google search form actually submitted your query?).  The identifiers are used as identifiers, general purpose clients don't try to extract semantics from the identifiers.

So using `/d8a496c4-51c5-4eeb-8cbd-d5e777cbdee7` as your identifier for the comment-count should "just work".

It's not particularly friendly to the human reader, of course, so you might prefer something else.  URI design is, in this sense, a lot like choosing a good variable name -- the machines don't care, so me make choices that are easier for the human beings to manage.  That normally means choosing a spelling that is "consistent" with the other spellings in your API.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) introduces distinctions between the path, the query, and the fragment, that you can expect general-purpose components to understand; one of the potentially important distinctions is that [reference resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5) describes how a general purpose component can compute a new identifier from a base uri and a relative reference.

```
/articles/comment-count + ./1 -> /articles/1
```